# Is changing the name of the .app file sufficient before submitting to Apple?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I tried submitting my application but was told that the file cannot contain any spaces. To fix this I simply renamed my .app file without the spaces, compressed it, and resubmitted. My question is was this sufficient, or do I need to rebuild my application without the spaces in the binary name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution will be sufficient concerning Apple's need to have a zip file without spaces. You don't need to rename the binary name.

However, in the future you should create your projects without spaces and if you need a space, you can set your ***Bundle display name*** in the plist file to the name with spaces that you need.